# Is there a maximum number of write operations per minute?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-quotas

Somehow I got in mind that the Data Store of the Google App Engine only allows 1000 writes / minute.
After I couldn't find any information on the web or in the quota docs I just wanted if someone can verify this information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen any mention of this.  There's a 1 write per second limit on an entity group, but you should be able to write to a very large number of entity groups at the same time.

Comment: Oh alright. So an entity group is one kind, right? And is this meant for the entire GAE/Data Store, or for one client that is trying to write? So if there are e.g. two clients at the same time, does one of them has to wait 1s after the other one did write something?

Comment: No, and entity group is completely unrelated to Kinds.  You should read up on ancestor paths and entity groups.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths

The limit is on entity groups, it has nothing to do with the client.  If you want your clients to wait on each other, you can build that, but I suspect it'll be difficult.  In most cases, clients will be oblivious of each other, so it's better to design your app so that clients will not write to the same entity group.